# Converting C# to vb.net error

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have converted a c# program to vb.net with a tool 
The program works fine in c#

in vb I get this error

```
Public member 'get_SymbolList' on type 'ConnectionControlClass' not found."}
```

at this line

```
oList = axTradeIdeasWindowX1.Connection.get_SymbolList(CType(i,Integer))
```

IN C#

This line works fine

```
oList = axTradeIdeasWindowX1.Connection.get_SymbolList(CType(i,Integer))
```

any ideas what the problem could be.
I have checked each and every line in the program list
walked through the Objects could not find `get_SymbolList` only found `SymbolList`
wonder if `get_` is a C# construct and if there is a vb.net equivalent

Comment: ..without seeing the `Connection` class it is impossible to say.. however it's probably because the converter has changed a property to a method.

Answer (score 7):

Clearly axTradeIdeasWindowX1 is an ActiveX object.  The C# code had to use the `get_` prefix on the SymbolList property because the C# language doesn't support indexed properties.  This is not a problem in COM nor in VB.NET.  Accordingly, the VB.NET compiler didn't turn the property in a method when it imported the interop library, like the C# compiler did.  There is no get_SymbolList() method anymore, only a SymbolList property.  You can see this by looking at the interop library with Object Browser.

So simply fix your problem by omitting the `get_` prefix.